# Allow wildcard (*) in tag filter in review queues, to enable filtering by groups of tags (e.g. multiple versions of a technology)

Tags: feature-request, tags, review, filtering

I have often set the Tag-Filter in the Close Votes to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and [silverlight](/questions/tagged/silverlight) to filter for questions with a technology where I am more confident with and can better determine if a question needs to be closed.

But this setting does not filter for question that use [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) or [silverlight-5.0](/questions/tagged/silverlight-5.0).

Please allow the wildcard (*) to be used in the Tag-Filter in the review queues, so that I can specify `silverlight-*` (as an example) as a filter.

[image: Tag-Filter in Close Votes]

Answer (score 5):

Great idea.

Allow me to propose a small extension:

You could also add an option to filter the close vote queue by the same tags that you use to filter your home page - favourite and ignored tags. Since it has the asterisk wildcard, the two features would complement each other nicely.

The purpose of this would be to ensure that the queue reflects the same areas of interest/expertise as your home page tag filter - presumably the languages and platforms you follow the most, and hence also the questions you are most qualified to judge.

And just to make it clear - I only suggest it as an option, so people could still filter their queue as they like, irrespectively of how they filter their home page.

Answer (score 0):

Given that one can use the wild card when searching via the search feature it should also be available for reviewing.

On the search bar the wildcard gets automatically translated into a list of subtags. That seems good behavior.

Similar behavior however conflicts with the 3 tag limit. That limit should just go.

Answer (score -2):

I might be going a bit tooo much .. but can we have parent/child relation kind of thing in tags .. like most of question i see in SQL Server are general to all sql server version so if we have SQL set as parent for all sql versions(like sql-server-2008 , tsql etc..) we can filter out whole SQL Server which will include all the SQL Server questions

Comment: Hmm, a tree/hierarchy of tags would be interesting

Comment: what is the problem with suggestion ?? if you wish to downvote just tell me what is the problem ??

Comment: This is a separate feature request. If you want a different feature, ask a new question.