# Filter review queues based on favorite tags and auto ignore the filter if it doesn't return any results

Tags: feature-request, review

It's easier for me to review posts that are tagged with one of my favorite tags, because I am more likely able to decide the correct action for the review task.

Therefore I think that reviewing could become more efficient if there was an option that installs a filter based on the users favorite tags.  Of course this filter could be limited to e.g. 3, maybe randomly chosen, tags for performance reasons.

Furthermore, the filter should get auto ignored if it doesn't return any results, so that the user can go on with reviewing without interrupting his workflow.

<sup>[Origin meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197051/156683)</sup>

Comment: There already is a filter option - but automatically populating that filter might be a good idea.

Comment: Yep I know, the idea is basically to guess the ideal filter for the user and automatically provide further tasks once the filter doesn't return any results.

Comment: A simple trick could already work: using GreaseMonkey (or similar), have the review links re-written to append a `tag=tagname` to the URL (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75952/192154)). "Filter by my favorite tags" is also already part of [this MSO request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208335/192154). There's also one for [wildcard filters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208560/192154).